# firefox brand new “new tab page” - how to see/edit blocked/pinned items?

Tags: firefox

While it's simple to pin/block a link-screenshot in the new beautiful tab page in firefox I see no way to edit the list of blocked/pinned items, does anybody know how to do it?
E.G. I blocked a page but now I woukld like to unlock, how to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is for FF17 on Windows, Mac/Linux users cf below

To unlock a blocked page quit Firefox, download [sqlitebrowser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/) at sourceforge.net (~6MB as of now, Windows only), use it to open chromeappsstore.sqlite in your "Profiles" directory. On Win Vista that's eg:

```
[DRIVENAME]:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\
Firefox\Profiles\[ALPHANUMERICSTRING].default\chromeappsstore.sqlite
```

Switch to the "browse data" tab, open the edit view of the value corresponding to the "pinned links" key (double click on it). Replace one entry (eg a **null**) with

```
{"url":"YOUR_URL","title":"YOUR_TITLE"}
```

apply changes, save changes.

There's a key "blocked links", too. Intuitively, deleting blocked urls from its value should help, but it didn't when I tried. The trick above is clumsy, but so far I couldn't google anything more elegant. I couldn't find anything useful searching Firefox' about:config tab, either. I found this solution when doing a string search for the blocked url in my profiles directory.

Mac/Linux users should find other sqlite browsers. When using the firefox addon [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) you would need to make a copy of the database file first and edit that. Afterwards quit Firefox and replace the old file with the new one.

Here's the bugzilla [entry](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=722234) ("Bug 722234 - [New Tab Page] provide an option to undo remove a site "), status is **assigned**, not **solved**. On comment reads: "Currently, there is now way to undo removal of a site or resetting the page using the new layout."

Answer (score 1):

There's an easier way to do it without downloading, especially for people who may not navigate computers very well. [Mozilla does have a way to do it](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/new-tab-page-show-hide-and-customize-top-sites?esab=a&s=New%20tab%20page&r=1&as=s#w_add-a-site), they just label it poorly and it's a bit roundabout.

Make the page you blocked on your new tabs page a Favorite, then click and drag to an empty space on your new tab page and it will autopin.  The one downside is that if you unpin it the site will disappear again.  I was frustrated for weeks after I removed Google and there doesn't seem to be much help out there that's simple.

Answer (score 1):

"Make the page you blocked on your new tabs page a Favorite"
What does that mean?  Bookmark?

I clicked the PIN icon on a couple and instead of pinning it, it seemed to completely remove that page from the New Tab selections altogether...and indeed, I see no way to get it back. Why would pinning something take it away!?  And they were pages I use many times every day; very disappointed.

And those that I clicked ARE in my bookmarks ('Favorites' is an IE term), but they have not reappeared as suggested above.

The  sqlitebrowser approach above is too complex and I can see it going awry trying to get all that right. Sad day here for me.